# How to get current Location by GPS or WiFi when MapActivity starts

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I have to load the current device Location when the MapActivity starts ( it start with an Intent launched from another Activity).
The problem is that looking around the web and in the android developer section I see that i have to use a LocationListener method onLocationChange(location), but i have to get the user location when the MapActivity starts, not when the user change his location. I have tried seveal ways but I don't find a solution.

```
public class MappaActivity extends MapActivity {

MapView miaMapView;
MapController mc;
LocationManager lm;
GeoPoint actualP;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mappa_activity);

    miaMapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.miaMapView);
    mc=miaMapView.getController();
    miaMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    miaMapView.setSatellite(true);
    miaMapView.invalidate();

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener=new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


//  This is MyLocationListener inner class:



private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){

            actualP = new
                    GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            mc.animateTo(actualP);
            mc.setZoom(10);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}
```

actualP remains null, onLocationChanged method is not fired until the user location is changed.

I also tried with locationManager.getLastKnowLocation(location.GPS_PROVIDER) but it returns null.

I hope to find some help, thanks!

Comment: Are you running this through an emulator or an actual device? And this might sound silly... but if you are using a device... have you gone outside to actually let it acquire a good GPS signal?

Comment: Did you add the permissions in the android manifest ?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >

Comment: yes, i added the permission, and yes, i tried going out to acquire GPS signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that your GPS_PROVIDER is unable to get the location

It will be better if you also use NETWORK_PROVIDER and PASSIVE_PROVIDER for getting the location when your  GPS_PROVIDER is unable to give you location

also use  lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);

and lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener); may be they are not that much accurate as GPS_PROVIDER.